# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to use **jquery.cookie** to handle the vertical accordion menu cookie.

```
var active = $.cookie('active'),
    $nav = $("#nav > li > a"),
    $active = $nav.filter('.' + active);

$nav.click(function(e, speed) {
    $("#nav li ul").slideUp(speed);
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown(speed);
        $.cookie('active', this);
    }
});
if ($active.next().is(':hidden')) {
    $active.trigger('click', [0]);
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9UXd/2/)</kbd>

When I click on dropdown menu I get this error on Firebug:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
```

I do not know what I did wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Tried it in chrome and firefox. both works ok

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if you refresh the page, cookie doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
$active = $nav.filter('.' + active);
```

If `active` is `""` (or anything that coerces to `""`), that becomes `$nav.filter(".")`, which is an invalid CSS expression. I get that exact error if I feed an invalid expression into `filter`.